# passing value from one list view to another

Tags: java, android, android-studio, expandablelistview

I am trying to pass a value through a listview to a listview on another activity using an onclicklistener. I am having serious trouble and cannot figure out how to do it properly.

Below is my code with the main expandable list view on it:

```
public class Menu extends AppCompatActivity {

ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
ExpandableListView expListView;
List<String> listDataHeader;
HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

    // get the listview
    expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

    // preparing list data
    prepareListData();

    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

    // setting list adapter
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}

//Preparing the list data

private void prepareListData() {
    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    // Adding child data
    listDataHeader.add("Starters");
    listDataHeader.add("Main Course");
    listDataHeader.add("Desserts");
    listDataHeader.add("Side Orders");
    listDataHeader.add("Drinks");

    // Adding child data
    final List<String> starters = new ArrayList<String>();
    starters.add("Soup of the Day");
    starters.add("Prawn Cocktail");
    starters.add("Liver Pate");
    starters.add("Caesar Salad");
    starters.add("Cheesy Garlic Bread");

    List<String> maincourse = new ArrayList<String>();
    maincourse.add("Steak Burger");
    maincourse.add("Pappardelle Pasta");
    maincourse.add("Fish and Chips");
    maincourse.add("Piri Piri Roast Chicken");
    maincourse.add("Roast Beef");

    List<String> desserts = new ArrayList<String>();
    desserts.add("Ice Cream Select");
    desserts.add("Chocolate Brownie");
    desserts.add("Creme Brullee");
    desserts.add("Sticky Toffee Pudding");
    desserts.add("Strawberry Meringue");

    List<String> sides = new ArrayList<String>();
    sides.add("Onion Rings");
    sides.add("Chunky Chips");
    sides.add("Tobacco Onions");
    sides.add("Chef's Veg");
    sides.add("Salad");

    List<String> drinks = new ArrayList<String>();
    drinks.add("Beer");
    drinks.add("Wine");
    drinks.add("Coke");
    drinks.add("Orange Juice");
    drinks.add("Tea");
    drinks.add("Coffee");

    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), starters); // Header, Child data
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), maincourse);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), desserts);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(3), sides);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(4), drinks);


    expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id)
        {

            final String selected = (String) parent.getSelectedItem();
            Intent i - new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DisplayOrder.class);
            i.putExtra("Name", selected);
            startActivity(i);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " : " + listDataChild.get(listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            return false;
        }
    });
}
}
```

Can anyone help with example code or advice? Would be very much appreciated, thanks

Comment: what you have done in another activity to get the data ? Please share that code too.

Comment: check this link for reference http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

Comment: Ive seen that tutorial, it only shows how to display a toast message when the item is selected

Comment: I havnt done anything in another activity, as im not sure what to do

Answer (score 0):

Use `public void setOnItemClickListener (AdapterView.OnItemClickListener l)` in Menu class. so u will get item position and then inside listener pass intent to DisplayOrder Activity with data.

In DisplayOrder Activity use `getIntent.getStringExtra("KEY");  //(If you are passing string)` to get intent data. Add that data in arrayList and set it to listview.

Hope it will help :)